# Android 3.0 socket response latency

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, latency

I have started an Android project utilizing socket programming. Platform is Android 3.0. Due to platform requirements I am applying the socket operations in AsyncTask.

I connect to the server, send commands successfully but the problem is that the responses I receive come incomplete. After sending a command, I have to wait for sometime for the response to come completely, otherwise it is just partial response. The way I found out I get the full response when I wait is during debug mode, I waited a while before going on to the next line of code which I utilize the response variable and I got the full expected result.

I tried putting a timer

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();

myTimer.wait(2000);
```

but that just made the whole response not work at all. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using some kind of sentinel value to indicate to the other end that the response is complete?

Comment: @Shane Wealti
There is no value specifically sent by my side, but there is always a beginning of the line indicator like command prompt like:

ServerName>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be having this problem. There is probably something wrong with your network connection, because that amount of latency is not normal for any platform. But if you do want to tackle it programmatically, read on.

You don't want to use a timer for that, because:

a) even after waiting you can't be certain you've got the value, and

b) you will be slowing things down unnecessarily if you do get the value quickly.

The better option is to have some code that checks the received value in a loop to see if it's complete, and once it is, move on to the next bit.

Comment: The solution you are suggesting is only valid if I know what response I am going to get every time. I now know the data is complete now since I am in my test environment and everything is static, your suggestion is not for a real time solution. But thanks a lot for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Just add a timeout - if so many seconds have gone by and you haven't received the full packet or made any progress toward it, assume an error in transmission and move on.

Comment: I can't just assume an error int transmission and just move on. I need to process other things with respect to that response.